# How to configure Squid for Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: email, proxy, squid

I have configured a Squid proxy server on RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.4. All my Windows clients have been configured to use the proxy at `192.168.5.100`, port `3128` when accessing the Internet.

However, Microsoft Outlook email clients are unable to access the Internet when sending  or receiving email.

My `iptables -P` output is as follows:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p TCP --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p TCP --dport 110 -j MASQUERADE INPUT DROP  
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i 192.168.5.100 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i 192.168.5.100 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i 192.168.5.100 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i 192.168.5.100 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i 192.168.5.100 -o 192.168.1.100 -j MASQUERADE
```

My `iptables -L` output is as follows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
`
```

Why is Outlook not working with the Squid proxy configuration?

Comment: Hello, let's add some more info about this, what gives you `iptables -L` ? what is your squid configuration ? if it is where is the iptable rule for this port. using masquerade plus a proxy is a bit strange in my opinion use either one or the other solution. Also what are you trying to do clearly, because you're goal not really identify here.

Comment: Also what are you trying to do clearly, because you're goal not really identify here

Comment: @Kiwy my goal is to allow my windows client machines to use microsoft outlook

Comment: as mention in the chat, Do you want to use an exchange server or just SMTP and IMAP ? what is your squid configuration ? you should first try to figure out what's not working before enabling iptables filtering.

Comment: Does turning the firewall off (`service iptables stop`) allow for the traffic to flow out? The squid proxy doesn't have anything to do with the Outlook email getting in/out. Squid is a HTTP proxy, for email that would be a SMTP proxy (i.e. a mail server).